# How to preload audio files in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on a media player right now but I am keen to find a solution where I can preload first 4 audio files and when I am going to next one the function with preload will run again. I am using an array with url path for each that points to s3 bucket not locally. I also want to mention that I am using `expo-av` package

For now the loading looks like this

```
componentDidMount() {
        Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            staysActiveInBackground: false,
            interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            shouldDuckAndroid: true,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false
        });
    }

    async _loadNewPlaybackInstance(playing) {
        if (this.playbackInstance != null) {
            await this.playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
            this.playbackInstance = null;
        }

        const source = { uri: PLAYLIST[this.index].url };
        const initialStatus = {
            shouldPlay: playing,
            rate: this.state.rate,
            shouldCorrectPitch: this.state.shouldCorrectPitch,
            volume: this.state.volume,
        };

        const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            source,
            initialStatus,
            this._onPlaybackStatusUpdate
        );
        this.playbackInstance = sound;

        if (status) {
            this._onPlayPausePressed()
        }

        this._updateScreenForLoading(false);
    }
```

Comment: When loading the page, show the indicator, and when you have completed all the functions that run the audio, make the indicator disappear.

Comment: @hongdevelop I guess you haven't understood my question. I don't want a loader. I want to download the files in cache. So when I will play the first audio file first 4 will be downloaded and stored in cache.